# In a Canvas App Form in Power Apps, how do I rename a value field to a column in a Collections while working with galleries?

Tags: canvas, collections, gallery, sharepoint-online, powerapps-canvas

How can I rename the columns in the collection, so that the data being entered by the user (they only see checkbox selections) is not showing the same in both SharePoint columns?  The values that the user sees are different for each column, yet, on submitting the form, the values in SharePoint are the same for both columns.

On the App Object in my Canvas App, I have programmed the "OnStart" property as:

```
Clear(PopArtCollection);
ForAll(
    'UserForm',
    Collect(
        ArtCollection,
        {
            'Products': ThisRecord.'Products',
            'Samples': ThisRecord.'Samples'
        }
    )
)
```

I have two columns in my SharePoint list that I've made galleries in the form ('Products' and 'Samples').

For each gallery checkbox, I am using the ArtCollection for the OnCheck and OnUnCheck controls.

OnCheck=

```
Collect(ArtCollection, ThisItem)
```

OnUnCheck=

```
Remove(ArtCollection, ThisItem)
```